# Redux woes: switch statement not registering action.type and not executing correct action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new with Redux and, to be honest, find it to be rather difficult and not intuitive at all to use. What I am trying to accomplish is just to load data from a file inside my app into a view just to get reducers and actions working correctly. I have a switch statement inside a projects_reducer.js file, an actions index.js, a projects.js view, and a reducer index.js as well. I've logged it out and the switch statement seems to be skipping the Fetch_Projects action every time and going to the default because action.type is not being registered correctly. I don't know why this is. Any help is appreciated. My code is included below.

```
//actions index.js file, only top two actions are relevant
import {Registrants, Projects} from '../../data';
export const Fetch_Users="Fetch_Users";
export const Fetch_Projects="Fetch_Projects";
export const Add_Project="Add_Project";
export const Add_User="Add_User";
export const Add_File="Add_File";
export const Delete_User="Delete_User";
export const Delete_Project="Delete_Project";
export const Delete_File="Delete_File";

export function fetchUsers(){
    return {
        type: Fetch_Users,
        payload: Registrants
    }
}


export function fetchProjects(){
    console.log("the fetch projects action!");
    return {
        type: Fetch_Projects,
        payload: Projects
    }
}


export function addUser(){
    return {
        type: Add_User,
        payload: "stuff"
    }
}

export function addProject(){
    return {
        type: Add_Project,
        payload: "stuff"
    }
}

export function addFile(){
    return {
        type: Add_File,
        payload: "stuff"
    }
}

export function deleteUser(){
    return {
        type: Delete_User,
        payload: "stuff"
    }
}

export function deleteProject(){
    return {
        type: Delete_Project,
        payload: "stuff"
    }
}

export function deleteFile(){
    return {
        type: Delete_File,
        payload: "stuff"
    }
}
```

projects_reducer.js file

```
import {Fetch_Projects, Add_Project, Delete_Project} from '../actions';
import {Registrants, Projects} from '../../data';

export default function(state={}, action){
    console.log("payload", action);
    switch(action.type){
        case Fetch_Projects:
            return Projects;
        case Add_Project:
            return state;
        case Delete_Project:
            return state;
        default:
        console.log("Well, you hit the default... :(")
            return state;
    }
}
```

reducers index.js

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {reducer as formReducer} from 'redux-form';

import ProjectsReducer from './projects_reducer';

const rootReducer=combineReducers({
    projects: ProjectsReducer
    //form: formReducer
});
```

export default rootReducer;
projects.js view

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import Table from './table';
import {fetchProjects} from '../actions';


class Projects extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        fetchProjects();
        console.log("props", this.props);
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Table />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {projects: state.projects}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchProjects})(Projects);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who might reference this question later, I did manage to solve this problem and the difficulty seems to have come from how I was calling the fetchProjects action in the projects.js view. I was calling it as just fetchProjects(), while the correct call was *this.props*.fetchProjects(). This must mean that react-redux adds the function(s) that you supply as mapDispatchToProps to props for you to call, although this is pretty tricky to a novice or the react-redux uninitiated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get an action to call your reducer and get the expected result, you must call your action by dispatching your action. In [docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#dispatch) you can see this.

> This is the only way to trigger a state change.

In your `componentDidMount` where you call `fetchProjects`, you are just calling a function, but not dispatching a function.

What you want to do is define the `mapDispatchToProps` function and attach the `dispatch` call to you `fethcProjects` function there.

Here is an example if that.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(Object.assign({}, todoActionCreators, counterActionCreators), dispatch)
  }
}
```

Although this example shows the usage of `bindActionCreators`, I should point out that there are ways of doing it without that which you can find in the docs.
The docs for this can be found [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md).

Alternatively, you can just bring in your store directly and call `store.dispatch(fetchProjects())`, but this is not the standard approach and I am merely demonstrating the usage of `dispatch`.

Comment: There's a much simpler way to pass in action creators - just pass them as an object as the second argument to `connect` instead of an actual `mapDispatch` function, and they will be bound automatically.

Comment: Yeah, thanks @markerikson , you are correct that the second argument to connect is mapDispatchToProps and I am currently passing fetchProjects in as the necessary function, so that is not the problem, I don't think. The problem is that the code in the reducer switch statement is not executing properly, still not sure why.

Comment: Maybe try adding `console.log(action.type, Fetch_Projects, action.type === Fetch_Projects)` at the start of that reducer to better understand what's happening?